# How to use map with a dictionary having regular expression keys?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, key

I have a DataFrame with a variable I want to map, using a dictionary where the keys are not "normal" strings, but regular expressions.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1']})
```

What I would like to do is `df['cat'].map({'A\d': 'a', 'B1': 'b'})`, but `A\d` seems not be interpreted as a regex. In this simple MWE I could do `df['cat'].map({'A1': 'a', 'A2': 'a', 'B1': 'b'})`, but in the real world, the regex is much more complicated. Also the dictionary is much more complicated, so that [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162202/pandas-series-replace-using-dictionary-with-regex-keys) (which requires to add start and end statementents and apply `re.compile` around the keys) is not feasable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use `replace` with `regex=True`

`map` takes a callable.   When you pass it a dictionary it replaces the dictionary with `lambda x: your_dict.get(x, x)`.  For your purposes, `replace` is appropriate.

```
df.replace({'A\d': 'a', 'B1': 'b'}, regex=True)

  cat
0   a
1   a
2   b
```

Comment: Duh, it sounds too good to be true. But it works. Although, `replace` is a little different than `map`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how complicated your dictionary is. But if it is not too long, we can just match and replace one by one:

```
maps = {'A\d': 'a', 'B1': 'b'}
(pd.concat((df['cat'].str.match(k) for k in maps), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
  .dot(pd.Series(d for k,d in maps.items()))
)
```

Output:

```
0    a
1    a
2    b
dtype: object
```